# Quick Text in Custom Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

As the title suggested I am wondering if it is possible to use the quick text functionality in Salesforce within a custom lightning component. I tried using a lightning:inputRichText field but did not see the Quick Text button appear.

Is this possible?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: were you able to do this?

Comment: We also have this use case